# Issue with firebase (Google Analytic ) not getting records in dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app.

I created and successfully add google-service.json file in app

but records /users are not updating in dashboard section of firebase console

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Have you added this line in application class? `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`

Comment: yes , I tried with this already. but not working